# Bash script to move file to trash, and append name if exists

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script to prompt a user for a filename, and if the file exists within the trash bin, increment the filename and then move it to trash.  For example, if "file1" exists in trash, it should re-name it "file1-1", if "file1-1" exists, it will be incremented to "file1-2", and so on.

This is what I have so far, but it will not work:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 echo "Select file name: "
 read fileName
 if $fileName in ~/.TRASH
     then
     echo "$fileName found."
     rename $fileName=$fileName+1
     trash $fileName
     echo "$fileName has been moved to trash."  
 else
     echo "$fileName not found."
     trash $fileName
     echo "$fileName has been moved to trash."
 fi
```

I'm assuming that there's something incorrect with the "if" or the rename/incremental counter, but for the life of me I cannot figure it out.

Comment: `if -e`? Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: I ran it through there and really couldn't get any pertinent information.  Basically, I am getting an error on line 4 "file1: command not found" and line 12 "trash: command not found."

Comment: `$fileName=$fileName+1` as an argument to `rename` looks funny to me. What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: If it is an option on your system and you don't want to do this as an exercise, I would recommend to simply use `trash-cli` to put stuff into trash via terminal. This will save you a whole lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

`if $fileName in ~/.TRASH` is not a thing. What you would do is this:

```
if [[ -e ~/.TRASH/"${fileName}" ]]
```

`rename $fileName=$fileName+1` is also not a thing. First, you'll need to [loop through the files backwards](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27400/3645) to avoid overwriting files with a higher number, then you need to pull off the relevant part of the filename, for example using `fileNumber="${fileName#*-}"`, then you can increment it using `let fileNumber++`, and finally you can use `mv` to move it.